# Can I control who can and can't initiate workflows

Tags: workflow, permissions

Is it possible to control who can and can't initiate workflows?

This seems like something that would be a standard feature but I can't find anything related to it. I looked into making a custom permission level but couldn't find anything in there related to workflows either.

If it's not an OOTB feature then I'm guessing it requires code to remove the workflow action from the ribbon, or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I think Minimum Contribute /Edit permission required to initiate the workflow. You can use sharepoint designer to modify workflow steps and set the permission who can start it.

Read these posts for more info:

- [what type of permission required to initiate Approval Workflow ?](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/98038c04-4607-4b33-9efd-13895fc27074/what-type-of-permission-required-to-initiate-approval-workflow?forum=sharepointadminprevious)
- [Minimum permission required to publish a workflow using Sharepoint designer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301820/minimum-permission-required-to-publish-a-workflow-using-sharepoint-designer)

Answer (score 0):

You can try a workaround to let the workflow end if the item which is being processed are modified/created by a specific user.